# My companion does nothing in battle. Why?

Tags: tales-of-zestiria

When I enter battle, my companion (currently Alisha) will just stand there doing nothing, she will just stand there taking hits until I have defeated all enemies myself.

Is this a bug, or some setting somewhere that is wrong? I am new to this game, and maybe I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that could be wrong.

Do you have a second controller on and connected?  In that case, the game probably thinks you're playing co-op.

With or without the extra controller, make sure her mode is set to auto.  This is on the arts menu screen at the top right, beneath the character icons.

[image]

You may accidentally have disabled the AI for the companion characters as well.  This is in a different menu - strategy, but I'm not sure it's possible to disable AI entirely for cpu-controlled characters from this menu.

Comment: thank you, I had set the control mode to manual, so that is why she wouldn't do anything